# json_decode is not working and echos nothing

Tags: php, json

I am having a lot of issues getting a response from json using php.
The code below echos nothing and I have no idea why. 
I need to be able to access all points of that json file individually through functions.

> file.json

```
{
    "file":{
        "name": "File Name",
        "description": "This is a file!",
        "license": "glp-2.0",
        "version": "1.1.1",
        "author": [{
            "name": "Author Name",
            "email": "name@domain.com"
        }],
        "require": [{
            "php": ">= 5.2.4",
            "myslq": ">= 5.0",
        }]
    }
}
```

> localhost/data.php

```
define('PATH', 'http://domain.com/json/');

function test(){
    $json = file_get_contents( PATH."file.json" );
    $data = json_decode($json,true);
    echo $data['file']['name'];
}

test();
```

Comment: do a `var_dump($json);` `var_dump($data);`

Comment: how do I get the name of the file? var_dump returns "NULL" when I call the function

Comment: the purpose of `var_dump($json)` is to check whether you've got any content from `file_get_contents`, if so, `var_dump($data)` checks whether it's converted to json object.

Comment: var_dump($json) works and prints a string of all the contents of the json file. var_dump($data) prints a string "NULL" onto the page. So now what? the purpose of the code in the question above is to use functions to grab individual data from the json file through php functions.

Comment: The content you got from `file.json` is not properly formatted. the line `"myslq": ">= 5.0",` with trailling `,` stuff up the format.

Answer (score 0):

```
define('PATH', 'http://domain.com/json/');

function test(){
    $json = file_get_contents( PATH."file.json" );
    $data = json_decode(preg_replace('/,\s*([\]}])/m', '$1', utf8_encode($json)),true);
    echo $data['file']['name'];
}

test();
```

**preg_replace('/,\s*([]}])/m', '$1', utf8_encode($json))**
In bold above fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to use a debugger or to do some debug print outs. 
Try:

```
$json = file_get_contents( PATH."file.json" );
var_dump($json);
$data = json_decode($json,true);
var_dump($data)
```

Now you can see if file_get_contents or json_decode doesn't work.

A much better option is to use a debugger while developing software in order to find failures easily. Get more information on: http://xdebug.org/.